# About 'Building Autoencoders in Keras'?

Tags: keras

I read the `Building Autoencoders in Keras`, the url is https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html
In the section of `Adding a sparsity constraint on the encoded representations`, I have tried according to his description, but the loss can't down to 0.11, instead around 0.26.

So the result is fuzzy:
[image]

Can anyone who has done this experiment tell me what's wrong  with it?

It's my code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras import regularizers

encoding_dim = 32 # 压缩后维度

input_img = Input(shape = (784,))
# 编码
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation = 'relu',
                activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(1e-4)
                )(input_img)
# 解码
decoded = Dense(784, activation = 'sigmoid')(encoded)

# 创建自动编码器
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

# 编码器
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)

encoded_input = Input(shape = (encoding_dim,))
# 最后一层全连接层作为解码器
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]

# 解码器
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

# 编译模块
autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')

from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], np.prod(x_train.shape[1:]))
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], np.prod(x_test.shape[1:]))

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, 
                epochs = 100,
                batch_size = 256,
                shuffle = True,
                validation_data = (x_test, x_test))


encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 4))
for i in range(10):
    # 原图
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.set_axis_off()

    # 解码后的图
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, n + i + 1)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.set_axis_off()

plt.savefig('simpleSparse.png')

from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: It's the same as the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code verbatim, and reproduced the error you got.

Solution: **reduce the batch size from 256, to 16.** You'll noice a huge difference in output even after 10 epochs of training.

Explanation: What is probably going on is that even though there is a reduction in your training loss, you are averaging the gradient over too many examples, to a point that the step you are taking in the direction of the gradient is cancelling itself out in some higher dimensional space and your learning algorithm is being tricked into thinking its converged to a local minima, when in reality it can't decided where to go. This last part explains why it seems that all the outputs you get look blurry and exactly the same.

**Update: Reduce batch size to 4, and you'll get near perfect reconstruction even after 10 epochs.**

Comment: For whatever reason, when I run this code (also verbatim), I get stuck at a loss of 0.28, with `batch_size=4`. Larger batches leads to larger losses. My output matches that of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the batch size in your code.

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,epochs = 10,batch_size = 16,shuffle = True,validation_data = (x_test, x_test))

Answer (score 0):

known bug. need to set regularizer to 10e-7

```
activity_regularizer=regularizers.activity_l1(10e-7))(input_img)
```

after 50 epochs, val_loss: 0.1424

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5414

If you drop your batch size it takes much longer